# Unknown column in 'on clause' with multiple joins

Tags: mysql

I wonder if someone might be able to help.

I am getting back error:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'sub_claims_volume.Claims_Volume' in 'on clause'

when I try to run the query below.

I think it has something to do with the join to the pi_loadings_claims_volume table.

I have generated a table from the sub query and had no problem making the join in that case and the correct result was returned.

```
SELECT bdx_pi_policy_accounts.policyid,
   bdx_pi_policy_accounts.renewal,
   sub_claims_volume.claims_volume,
   pi_loadings_claims_volume.loading
FROM   bdx_pi_policy_accounts
   LEFT JOIN pi_loadings_claims_volume
   ON sub_claims_volume.claims_volume =
   pi_loadings_claims_volume.claims_per_year

LEFT JOIN (SELECT pi_claims.policyid,
    RIGHT(pi_claims.policykey, 1) AS Renewal,
    Count(pi_claims.claimid)      AS Claims_Volume
    FROM   pi_claims
    GROUP  BY pi_claims.policyid,
    pi_claims.policykey) AS sub_claims_volume
    ON bdx_pi_policy_accounts.policyid = sub_claims_volume.policyid
    AND bdx_pi_policy_accounts.renewal = sub_claims_volume.renewal
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it shows Unknown column error is because when the `join` is performed with `pi_loadings_claims_volume` table, `sub_claims_volume` table alias is not known (as i) and hence, query can't recognize `Claims_Volume` column.

Repositioning the tables in `join` (i.e. placing `sub_claims_volume` query before `join` condition) should fix it, e.g.:

```
SELECT bdx_pi_policy_accounts.policyid,
   bdx_pi_policy_accounts.renewal,
   sub_claims_volume.claims_volume,
   pi_loadings_claims_volume.loading
FROM   bdx_pi_policy_accounts
LEFT JOIN (SELECT pi_claims.policyid,
    RIGHT(pi_claims.policykey, 1) AS Renewal,
    Count(pi_claims.claimid)      AS claims_volume
    FROM   pi_claims
    GROUP  BY pi_claims.policyid,
    pi_claims.policykey) sub_claims_volume
    ON bdx_pi_policy_accounts.policyid = sub_claims_volume.policyid
    AND bdx_pi_policy_accounts.renewal = sub_claims_volume.renewal  
LEFT JOIN pi_loadings_claims_volume
   ON sub_claims_volume.claims_volume =
   pi_loadings_claims_volume.claims_per_year
```

Comment: Darshan, Thank you very much. I had not considered repositioning the join. This works perfectly. Best Regards. Dan

Comment: Please add some context to your answer, explaining what you changed and why. This will make your answer more helpful to future visitors.

Comment: @miken32 added the context